# Replace blank cells in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For some reason, when this is 0 it wont say 0 or even give a null value, it just returns nothing (attached screenshot)

How can I get this to return 0 instead? And can someone explain why this is happening?

```
select 
    cast(PatientClass as varchar) + ' - ' +  cast([Counted] as varchar) [Procedures Split]
from 
    (select 
         PatientClass, COUNT(*) as [Counted]
     from
         (SELECT                    
              NELCal.LastDayOfWeek, S.FaciltyID, 
              PP.EncounterRecno, PP.ProcedureSequence, 
              S.[AdmissionDate], S.AdmissionConsultantName, S.AdmissionMethod,
              s.LengthOfSpell,
              year(S.[AdmissionDate]) as AdmYear,
              month(S.[AdmissionDate]) as AdmMonth,
              PP.[ProcedureDate],
              year(PP.[ProcedureDate]) as ProcYear,
              month(PP.[ProcedureDate]) as ProcMonth,
              S.Age, S.[AdmissionSpecialty(Function)],
              S.[PatientClass], s.[AdmissionSpecialty(Main)],
              PP.[ProcedureCode], PP.[Procedure]
          FROM 
              [WHREPORTING].[APC].[Spell] S                 
          LEFT JOIN 
              [WHREPORTING].[APC].[Episode] E ON S.SourceSpellNo = E.SourceSpellNo                  
          LEFT JOIN 
              [WHREPORTING].[APC].[AllProcedures] PP ON E.EpisodeUniqueID = PP.EpisodeSourceUniqueID
          LEFT JOIN
              WHREPORTING.APC.Patient P ON P.EncounterRecno = S.EncounterRecno
          JOIN 
              WHREPORTING.LK.Calendar AS NELCal ON PP.ProcedureDate = NELCal.TheDate                    
                                                AND pp.ProcedureDate between '05 dec 2016' and '06 dec 2016'            
            --and NELCal.LastDayOfWeek between DATEADD(DAY,-7*52,cast(GETDATE() as DATE))                   
            --and DATEADD(DAY,-1,cast(GETDATE() as DATE))                   
          WHERE                 
              [AdmissionSpecialty(Function)] = 'Breast Surgery') f          
    group by 
        PatientClass) g
```

[image]

Comment: that's possibly because you've got a GROUP BY, but there might be nothing to group - if you take the group by away, are there any rows to group?

Comment: You are calling the COUNT aggregate on a derived table that may not contain any records; this will result in nothing being returned.

Comment: You need to select all the distinct 'PatientClass' that you are interested in - then LEFT JOIN that to all your selected records - then count over the RIGHT side table (which could be null - nulls are not counted) then you can get zero for a 'PatientClass' that has zero rows – Cato just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `case` statment

```
CASE WHEN yourfield = ''  THEN 0 ELSE yourfield
```

If not records are returned at all you can do this

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select 
    cast(PatientClass as varchar) + ' - ' +  cast([Counted] as varchar) [Procedures Split]
from 
    (select 
         PatientClass, COUNT(*) as [Counted]
     from
         (SELECT                    
              NELCal.LastDayOfWeek, S.FaciltyID, 
              PP.EncounterRecno, PP.ProcedureSequence, 
              S.[AdmissionDate], S.AdmissionConsultantName, S.AdmissionMethod,
              s.LengthOfSpell,
              year(S.[AdmissionDate]) as AdmYear,
              month(S.[AdmissionDate]) as AdmMonth,
              PP.[ProcedureDate],
              year(PP.[ProcedureDate]) as ProcYear,
              month(PP.[ProcedureDate]) as ProcMonth,
              S.Age, S.[AdmissionSpecialty(Function)],
              S.[PatientClass], s.[AdmissionSpecialty(Main)],
              PP.[ProcedureCode], PP.[Procedure]
          FROM 
              [WHREPORTING].[APC].[Spell] S                 
          LEFT JOIN 
              [WHREPORTING].[APC].[Episode] E ON S.SourceSpellNo = E.SourceSpellNo                  
          LEFT JOIN 
              [WHREPORTING].[APC].[AllProcedures] PP ON E.EpisodeUniqueID = PP.EpisodeSourceUniqueID
          LEFT JOIN
              WHREPORTING.APC.Patient P ON P.EncounterRecno = S.EncounterRecno
          JOIN 
              WHREPORTING.LK.Calendar AS NELCal ON PP.ProcedureDate = NELCal.TheDate                    
                                                AND pp.ProcedureDate between '05 dec 2016' and '06 dec 2016'            
            --and NELCal.LastDayOfWeek between DATEADD(DAY,-7*52,cast(GETDATE() as DATE))                   
            --and DATEADD(DAY,-1,cast(GETDATE() as DATE))                   
          WHERE                 
              [AdmissionSpecialty(Function)] = 'Breast Surgery') f          
    group by 
        PatientClass) g)

SELECT 0 AS [Procedures Split]
ELSE
select 
    cast(PatientClass as varchar) + ' - ' +  cast([Counted] as varchar) [Procedures Split]
from 
    (select 
         PatientClass, COUNT(*) as [Counted]
     from
         (SELECT                    
              NELCal.LastDayOfWeek, S.FaciltyID, 
              PP.EncounterRecno, PP.ProcedureSequence, 
              S.[AdmissionDate], S.AdmissionConsultantName, S.AdmissionMethod,
              s.LengthOfSpell,
              year(S.[AdmissionDate]) as AdmYear,
              month(S.[AdmissionDate]) as AdmMonth,
              PP.[ProcedureDate],
              year(PP.[ProcedureDate]) as ProcYear,
              month(PP.[ProcedureDate]) as ProcMonth,
              S.Age, S.[AdmissionSpecialty(Function)],
              S.[PatientClass], s.[AdmissionSpecialty(Main)],
              PP.[ProcedureCode], PP.[Procedure]
          FROM 
              [WHREPORTING].[APC].[Spell] S                 
          LEFT JOIN 
              [WHREPORTING].[APC].[Episode] E ON S.SourceSpellNo = E.SourceSpellNo                  
          LEFT JOIN 
              [WHREPORTING].[APC].[AllProcedures] PP ON E.EpisodeUniqueID = PP.EpisodeSourceUniqueID
          LEFT JOIN
              WHREPORTING.APC.Patient P ON P.EncounterRecno = S.EncounterRecno
          JOIN 
              WHREPORTING.LK.Calendar AS NELCal ON PP.ProcedureDate = NELCal.TheDate                    
                                                AND pp.ProcedureDate between '05 dec 2016' and '06 dec 2016'            
            --and NELCal.LastDayOfWeek between DATEADD(DAY,-7*52,cast(GETDATE() as DATE))                   
            --and DATEADD(DAY,-1,cast(GETDATE() as DATE))                   
          WHERE                 
              [AdmissionSpecialty(Function)] = 'Breast Surgery') f          
    group by 
        PatientClass) g
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it still gives me nothing back?

Comment: In that case there are no records I will update my answer

Comment: @IvanStarostin Ok please post a solution that doesn't require any more load on the server...

Comment: You have already given a tip to yourself: if the original source has nothing in it then you should give some surrogate source to your script.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @Alec. Imagine that the original query execution time is about 1 hour (when there are data for that). After modification now it would be executing by 2 hours. Additional hour for an empty string? And this is the only solution?

Comment: This is the only working solution I could think of, as before I welcome an answer that achieves the correct result in a nicer way.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that one of your sub-queries returns no records. This means that your resultset will totally empty (not even null).

If the result is empty, you can't work with the fields (i.e. your cast statement). You need to first check for [IF EXISTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx)...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the Coalesce function like this:

```
select Coalesce(Table.Field,0) as columnResult
```